Why doesn't my code correctly compare the strings in my array and the one from scanf?
I am writing a simple guessing game, just as a beginner thing. This code iterates through the array of words that I have set up and checks it against the input string to see if they are the same. If they are, it returns 1 (correct), and if not, it returns 0 (incorrect). The problem seems to be that it always returns 0, no matter if it is right or wrong. Why is this occurring?
#include <stdio.h>

int itrThroughWords(char *string) {
    int guessIsCorrect;

    const char* words[] = {"Wall", "Insect", "Cereal", "Skateboard"};
    for (int g = 0; g <= 3; g++) {
        if (string == words[g]) {
            guessIsCorrect = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            guessIsCorrect = 0;
            printf("%d", guessIsCorrect); // this just prints four zeros each time
        }
    }

    return guessIsCorrect;
}

int main() {
    printf("Guessing game! Guess a word correctly and you win!\n");
    char wordGuess[20];
    int correctGuess;

    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("Attempts remaining: %d | ", i);
        scanf("%s", wordGuess);
        correctGuess = itrThroughWords(wordGuess);

        if (correctGuess == 1) {
            printf("You have guessed correctly!");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Incorrect :( Guess again!\n");

        }
    }

    return 0;
}


You can't directly compare strings in c as it itself is an array of characters. Try using strcmp in the strings.h module

@moochandaleech, What do your think happens with char wordGuess[20]; ... scanf("%s", wordGuess); with input like "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"?

You can't directly compare strings in c try using
#include <string.h>
int itrThroughWords(char *string) {
    const char words[4][11] = {"Wall", "Insect", "Cereal", "Skateboard"};
    for (int g = 0; g < 4; g++) {
        if (strcmp(string, words[g]) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

This also fixes the logical errors in the code that 
you defined "const char* word[]" which means it is an constant array with no bound defined of pointers to chars not a 2d array of chars as it should be.
Also printing 0 is also unneeded as you handle it in your main function anyways.
